# Having issues fetching Google Map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, error-handling, fetch-api

[image: googlemapapi]

I'm having issues fetching Google Map, it says the page can't load correctly, I also have some errors on my console. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong, I should be able to make a query and have the places showing in the suggestions, but I'm doing something wrong. Here is my component, I have also attached a photo. All help will be welcome .

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Map, Marker, GoogleApiWrapper } from "google-maps-react";

const apiKey = process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_API_KEY;



const center = {
  lat: 51.5074,
  lng: 0.1278,
};

let service = null;

export class MapContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      input: "",
      suggestions: [],
      places: [],
    };
  }

  savePlace = (place) => {
    this.setState({ places: [...this.state.places, place] });
  };

  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ input: e.target.value });
  };

  handleKeyPress = (event) => {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
      this.search();
    }
  };

  

  search = () => {
  const {input} = this.state;
   service.textSearch({query: input}, (suggestions) => {
     this.setState({suggestions});
   })
   
  };

  initPlaces(mapProps, map) {
    const { google } = mapProps;
    service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  }

  render() {

    const { suggestions, places } = this.state;

  

    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col">
            <div className="form-inline d-flex justify-content-between mb-4">
              <input
                type="text"
                value={this.state.input}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                className="form-control flex-grow-1"
                placeholder="Search for places on Google Maps"
                onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress}
              />
              <button onClick={this.search} className="btn btn-primary ml-2">
                Search
              </button>
            </div>
            <h3>Suggestions</h3>
            <ul className="list-group">
              {suggestions.map((place, i) => (
                <li
                  key={i}
                  className="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center"
                >
                  <div>
                    <div>
                      <strong>{place.name}</strong>
                    </div>
                    <span className="text-muted">
                      {place.formatted_address}
                    </span>
                  </div>

                  <button
                    className="btn btn-outline-primary"
                    onClick={() => this.savePlace(place)}
                  >
                    Show
                  </button>
                </li>
              ))}
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div className="col">

          <Map google={this.props.google} zoom={14} initialCenter={center} onReady={this.initPlaces}></Map>
            
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default GoogleApiWrapper({
  apiKey,
})(MapContainer);
```

[image]

Comment: Seems like a simple fix. You need to add your API key to your requests.

Comment: I did put the API key on my .env file and then on the component like this : const apiKey = process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_API_KEY;

Comment: I must done something wrong because the console does not recognise the Api key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked your code and if you directly put your API key in your 
`const apiKey = "PUT_YOUR_API_KEY_HERE";` , it will properly show your map.

It seems that you are putting your variables in the `.env file` (refer [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/) on how to add custom environment variables). Make sure that you put your `.env file` outside the src folder and set this inside your .env file : 
`REACT_APP_GOOGLE_API_KEY=API_KEY_VALUE_HERE`. This works for me.

You can find the sample code in this [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-grass-3s1u9).

Make sure to change the value of the `REACT_APP_GOOGLE_API_KEY` in the .env file to your API key.

Hope this helps!